MS AD replacement
With Microsoft Recall being thrown out, I have been asked to roll out a test system for replacing Windows desktops with Linux. I need to know if there is any currently available software that can manage users of the Linux systems, while still using Microsoft Active Directory.
I need to allow network users access to a Linux PC, without having to set them up on the computer first. Have it connect to an existing AD environment and authenticate.

MS AD does a lot of things. LDAP is the usual for authentication and user management, but without knowing what you're going to do with it, this can't be answered.

I need to allow network users access to a linux pc, without having to set them up on the computer first.Have it connect to an existing AD environment and authenticate.

@300cpilot there are integrations able to be implemented on Desktop now since 22.04.  Ubuntu has documentation on this for both Server and Desktop at this link using SSSD to implement the integrations.  https://documentation.ubuntu.com/server/how-to/sssd/with-active-directory/

Debian and Ubuntu systems have been able to integrate with AD for login purposes for some time using SSSD and other utilities.
Since 22.04 however these have desktop integrations and can be used for user authentication.  Group Policy and other enforcement requires Ubuntu Pro subscriptions per device to use ADSys.
Because this documentation changes from release to release with updates, I recommend you refer to Ubuntu's official documentation for implementing SSSD and configuration.  You will need to do some prework on each system to set up SSSD but then your GUI will have integration.
You will still have to go through initial Ubuntu setup and setup a local account on the system in order to gain access to the system to install things, etc. That is equivalent to on a Windows system setting it up with a local account before domain joining it.


(Note that while this is effectively a "link only answer", the process of integration with SSSD and ADsys (if you go that route with Ubuntu Pro) is nontrivial and varies based on what you're setting up and implementing - therefore providing you with the documentation and/or whitepaper on how to do this is the only real way you can solve this problem)

